# Using LINQ or Lambda instead of nested and multiple foreach statements

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to use a better syntax than nested `foreach` statements to overwrite the initial list with items from the second list.

In the code below:

- I want to overwrite `initialList` with those in `secondList` that have the same `Value` (Remove Red).
- Use the items in `secondList` where `Value` was the same (Yellow)

New `initialList` list should include (Green and Yellow).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int useProd = 2;
    int useDomain = 0;

    var person1 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "foo", domainId = 0, Name = "Red" };
    var person2 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "bar", domainId = 0, Name = "Green" };
    var person3 = new Person() { prodId = 1, Value = "foo", domainId = 1, Name = "Yellow" };

    var initialList = new List<Person>();
    initialList.Add(person1);
    initialList.Add(person2);

    var secondList = new List<Person>();
    secondList.Add(person3);

    List<Person> personsToRemove = new List<Person>();
    List<Person> personsToUpdate = new List<Person>();

    foreach (var pers1 in initialList)
    {
        foreach (var pers2 in secondList)
        {
            if (pers1.Value == pers2.Value)
            {
                personsToRemove.Add(pers1);
                personsToUpdate.Add(pers2);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var remPers in personsToRemove)
    {
        initialList.Remove(remPers);
    }
    foreach (var updPers in personsToUpdate)
    {
        initialList.Add(updPers);
    }
    foreach (var item in initialList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value: {0}, prodId: {1}, domainId: {2}, Name: {3}", item.Value, item.prodId, item.domainId, item.Name));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
public class Person
{
    public int prodId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int domainId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: It's unclear to me what is being done exactly. Can you clarify what the business idea behind the code is?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The code is overly simplified from business code. I need to Union two lists. I cannot just add both together, I need to overwrite the initialList objects with the objects from secondList where property Value is the same. And I also need all object from secondList that dont exists in initialList added. When foreach statements finds initial.Value == second.Value it Remove(initial object), and Add(second object) instead. Is there another way to do this in Linq or Lambda?

Comment: When you say "*I also need all object from secondList that dont exists in initialList*", how do you determine something doesn't exist in `initialList`? What determines uniqueness?

Comment: The uniqueness comes from other properties like Id column in the DB, as I said its a very simplified example, theres more properties on the object. When I create initialList and secondList in the business code they get populated from DB but secondList is differentiated on a Id column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` which only compares the `Value` property like

```
public class PersonValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) { return true; }
        if (x == null || y == null) { return false; }

        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.Value == null) {return 0;}
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

you can by using linq methods replace the loops by

```
        PersonValueComparer valueComparer = new PersonValueComparer();
        initialList = secondList.Where(p => initialList.Contains(p, valueComparer))
            .Concat(initialList.Where(p => !secondList.Contains(p, valueComparer))).ToList();
```

We are first using the `Where()` method to filter the `secondList` for items which are in the `initialList` . Then we use `Concat()` to add the `Person''s which are not in the`secondList`.

---

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) properties should be named using `PascalCase` casing.

---

You should always use meaningful and descriptive names for naming methods, variables, properties and classes so **Sam the Maintainer** sees at first glance what it is about.

---

Shortening variable names doesn't add any value but instead reduces readability which **Sam the Maintainer** doesn't like.

---

Comment: Isn't the .Select completely worthless in this example?

Comment: @insta you are right. Updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

Since you mentioned in the comments that you want the union of the two lists, you could  perform a LINQ [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx).  There are a few ways to do it:

### Use `IEnumerable<T>.Union(IEnumerable<T>)`

If you go with the simpler overload for `Union`, you need to implement `IEquatable<T>` and override `GetHashCode` on `Person`.
For simplicity, my example will look only at the Value property:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public int prodId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int domainId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
       return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
       return Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
       return other != null
              && other.Value == Value;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<Person>
                {
                   new Person {Value = "bob"},
                   new Person {Value = "alice"},
                };

    var list2 = new List<Person>
                {
                   new Person {Value = "bob"},
                   new Person {Value = "charles"},
                };

    var unionedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
}
```

### Use `IEnumerable<T>.Union(IEnumerable<T>, IEqualityComparer<T>)`

If you go with this option, you could use @Heslacher's equality comparer as the parameter for the [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358407%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) call.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<Person>
                {
                   new Person {Value = "bob"},
                   new Person {Value = "alice"},
                };

    var list2 = new List<Person>
                {
                   new Person {Value = "bob"},
                   new Person {Value = "charles"},
                };

    var unionedList = list1.Union(list2, new PersonValueComaparer()).ToList();
}
```

### Order Matters

Since you want `secondList` to win in any conflicts, you would use `secondList.Union(initialList)`, so any matches would defer to the objects in `secondList`.

Comment: @Heslacher I mentioned that at the end, but with the formatting, I can see that it could easily be missed.  I will re-format the answer a little.

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
var peopleToAdd = secondList.Where(p1 => initialList.Any(p2 => p1.Value == p2.Value)).ToList();
initialList.RemoveAll(p1 => secondList.Any(p2 => p1.Value == p2.Value));
initialList.AddRange(peopleToAdd);
```

Step 1 - look at the second list and find all people that need to be added to the first list. We are looking for all the people that have the same `Value` in both lists. Note: Execute `.ToList()` to get the result before the Step 2 is executed.

```
var peopleToAdd = secondList.Where(p1 => initialList.Any(p2 => p1.Value == p2.Value)).ToList();
```

Step 2 - Remove all the people from the first list that occur in the second list with the same `Value`.

```
initialList.RemoveAll(p1 => secondList.Any(p2 => p1.Value == p2.Value));
```

Note: Micro-optimization for the Step 2, you can use `peopleToAdd` instead of `secondList` since we've already discovered matching people.

```
initialList.RemoveAll(p1 => peopleToAdd.Any(p2 => p1.Value == p2.Value));
```

Step 3 - add all the people found in Step 1 to the `initialList`.

```
initialList.AddRange(peopleToAdd);
```

Comment: does my explanation make sense now?

Comment: Much Better. thank you. we like more explanation here on Code Review.  thank you for taking the time to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

What you are actually doing is updating the `initialList` with objects from `secondList` based on matching `Value`. 
The optimal solution would have an O(N+M) comparisons (N and M - number of elements in both lists, while your solution performs O(N*M) comparisons.

In order to make your code simpler I suggest to use the lookup table like this:

```
var lookup = secondList.ToLookup(person => person.Value);

initialList = initialList
    .Select(person => lookup[person.Value].FirstOrDefault() ?? person).ToList();
```

We "walk" through the `secondList` collection once to build a lookup table, and go through the `initialList` list once to replace elements that match the item in `lookup`.